# Android: RecyclerView OnAnimationEnd?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Is there any way to set `OnAnimationEndListener` on a `RecyclerView` so that it will be called when the `RecyclerView` ends it's animation (eg: when adding or removing items) ?

```
recyclerView.setOnAnimationEnd(...);
```

Comment: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#isRunning(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener)

Comment: anyway to register for future animation ends also ?

Comment: this only works one time , registering the listener for current running animation not for all future ones.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#mFinishedListeners ^F mFinishedListeners